# Is there a theoretical equation for the $d$-spacing for an amorphous solid or a metastable crystal?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, material-science, x-ray-crystallography, amorphous-solids

So I am trying to study and compare two different samples (thin films) of the same material but with different cooling rates. I made one that was cooled slowly, allowing it to nucleate and crystallize properly and the other one was quenched from a high temperature to room temperature almost instantly.

Now I could use the $d$-spacing equation for a monoclinic structure for the slow cooled sample and assign all (110) peaks to the experimental data nicely. The problem is now I'm trying to understand the metastable (quenched) sample. I'm not sure if there are any equations or models that can be used to fit my experimental data.

If anyone has any thoughts on this please share.

Comment: What is the composition of these thin films?

Comment: The composition is C30 H32 S2, but I'm looking for a general answer. Like is there a model that tries to fit XRD data for a metastable/amorphous crystal?

Answer (score 0):

A crystal has a long-range ordered arrangement of atoms and therefore it produces a sharp diffraction pattern. If your quenched specimen is crystalline then it should produce a sharp diffraction pattern and relatively low background upon proper experiment conditions; if the quenched specimen is amorphous it should produce a characteristic broad background. If it is partially crystallized then you will see both: sharp diffraction on a broad background.

Note that different thermal histories may result in different phases/crystal structures or possibly a mixture of them.